# What does #[automatically_derived] mean?

Tags: rust

I found `#[automatically_derived]` in the [serde-derive](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/4e54aaf7963c3580cc50b56842949b0ce6b3a997/serde_derive/src/ser.rs#L48) crate when generating the implementations for the derived type:

```
quote! {
    #[automatically_derived]
    impl #impl_generics _serde::Serialize for #ident #ty_generics #where_clause {
        fn serialize<__S>(&self, __serializer: __S) -> _serde::export::Result<__S::Ok, __S::Error>
        where
            __S: _serde::Serializer,
        {
            #body
        }
    }
}
```

What does this mean? When I should use this?

I also found this in several expanded macros, but I couldn't find any description about this line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is an indication to the compiler that [the marked code should not be reported as unused](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.41.1/src/librustc_passes/liveness.rs#L360-L368), among other things:

```
// Don't run unused pass for #[derive()]
if let FnKind::Method(..) = fk {
    let parent = ir.tcx.hir().get_parent_item(id);
    if let Some(Node::Item(i)) = ir.tcx.hir().find(parent) {
        if i.attrs.iter().any(|a| a.check_name(sym::automatically_derived)) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It also applies to

- [ignoring single use lifetimes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.41.1/src/librustc/middle/resolve_lifetime.rs#L1628-L1632)

Comment: Is there a list of all compiler indications?

Comment: @Tim [are you looking for this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3b7720399a9006d9d7b89c251fa37ead46f9db7a/src/libsyntax/feature_gate.rs#L695-L1081)? The list changes over time.

Comment: It's at least a list of all currently available attributes, thank you!